# Correct dependence for "Local Coloring"

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, graph-colorings

In Alon-Spencer's book, Probabilistic Lens #8, it is proven that for each $k$, there exists $\epsilon = \epsilon(k)>0$ such that for all large $n$, there exists an $n$-vertex graph $G$ with chromatic number $> k$, yet every subgraph of $G$ on $\epsilon n$ vertices has chromatic number $\le 3$.

The proof given there tells us that we can take $\epsilon(k) \gg \frac{1}{k^9 \log^{O(1)}(k)}$. Meanwhile, it is obvious that $\epsilon(k) \le 3/k$. I'm curious what the truth is, asymptotically (or at least the best known bounds).